# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. Running Android App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm gotting this error message when i run my android projet.
It is a portable project.

> The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006:
>   Reference to metadata item
>   'Mono.Security.Interface.MonoTlsProviderFactoryDelegate' (defined in
>   'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065') from 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' could not be
>   resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
>   Mono.Security.Interface.MonoTlsProviderFactoryDelegate    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext&
>   context)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception
>   innerException, String message, Object[] args)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

This is my target:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: You have an incorrect assembly reference your `Xamarin.Android` project as it is pulling in `.MonoTlsProviderFactoryDelegate` from `Xamarin.iOS`

Comment: Do you know where is it from ? I dont found this name on my project.

Comment: Check your assembly references in your each of your projects, somewhere you probably added a manual reference to the wrong assembly...

Answer (score 1):

I found a weird reference to Xamarin.iOS. When I removed that, it worked well.
[image: screenshot from my PC]